# making assertions in Geb JUnit4 tests

Tags: grails, geb

I'm using Geb to do some functional testing of a Grails app. I'm using Geb's integration with JUnit4, i.e. my test classes extend `geb.junit4.GebReportingTest`.

Should I make assertions using Java's keyword, e.g.

```
assert 2 == 1 + 1
```

or JUnit's assert* methods, e.g.

```
Assert.assertTrue 2 == 1 + 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `assert` keyword. This way you will be able to leverage [Groovy's power assert](http://hamletdarcy.blogspot.com.au/2009/05/new-power-assertions-in-groovy.html) feature.